# Impala substr can't get utf8 character correctly

Tags: hadoop, impala

I am new to ETL and I was assigned with a task on sanitizing some sensitive information before giving the data to a client.

I am using HUE web client with Impala.

What I want to do is:

For example, a column info like `'京客隆（三里屯店）'`, then I need to transform it into something like `'京XXX店）'` .

My query is:

```
select '京客隆（三里屯店）', concat(substr('京客隆（三里屯店）', 1, 3), 'XXX', substr('京客隆（三里屯店）', char_length('京客隆（三里屯店）') -6, 6));
```

But I get gibberish in the output:

```
'京客隆（三里屯店）' | concat(substr('京客隆（三里屯店）', 1, 3), 'xxx', substr('京客隆（三里屯店）', char_length('京客隆（三里屯店）') - 6, 6))    
京客隆（三里屯店）   |   京XXX�店�
```

The problem is that :

`select '京客隆（三里屯店）', substr('京客隆（三里屯店）', char_length('京客隆（三里屯店）') -3 , 3);`

output: `京客隆（三里屯店）      ��`

doesn't get the correct characaters. **Why is that?** I pasted the string in python shell and I can get the correct characters if I only take the last 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I misunderstood the function `substr`.

`substr(STRING a, INT start [, INT len])` :

It takes characters **starting from (including)** `INT start`. So for example my string `'京客隆（三里屯店）'` is `27` bytes long in total, and each utf8 char takes 3 bytes here. I need to take the last `3` bytes, which is the `）` , then I need to write:

`substr('京客隆（三里屯店）, 27 - 2 ,3 )` .

It then gets the `25, 26, 27` 3 bytes and display the char  `）` correctly.

---

Updated:

I was told to use :

`SELECT regexp_replace('京客隆（三里屯店）', '(.)(.*)(.{2})', '\\1***\\3');`

works like an charm :P.